# Can we use keyboard & mouse on PS3?

Tags: ps3, keyboard, mouse

Can we use **wireless** keyboard & mouse on PS3 with **minimum** loss and delay?

I've searched on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ps3+keyboard+%26+mouse&aq=f), and i saw a lot of videos about this. But i don't think that methods would be healty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes.** To add a Bluetooth keyboard, go to Settings > Accessories > Manage Bluetooth Devices.

For a non-Bluetooth wireless keyboard to work, it would probably have to have its own wireless receiver that would plug into the console via USB.

It also supports USB keyboards.  From page 31 of my PS3 owner's manual:

> ## Using a USB keyboard
>
> You can enter characters using a USB keyboard (sold separately). While the text entry screen is displayed, if any key on the connected USB keyboard is pressed, the text entry screen will enable you to use the USB keyboard.
>
> ### Hint
>
> You cannot use the predictive mode when using a USB keyboard.

Unfortunately, [it looks like there aren't many games that natively support keyboard/mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3_accessories#List_of_games_which_can_utilise_a_keyboard_and.2For_mouse). I did find the [Eagle Eye](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0040UAYI4), a **third-party adapter that allows you to use a USB keyboard/mouse in lieu of a controller** regardless of whether or not the games supports it.

Answer (score 3):

Although you can use a mouse and keyboard, you *can't play games* with them. They are very much limited to configurations and forms. The browsing becomes much better as well.

Comment: I was actually very surprised that this is sometimes wrong. In Black Ops, if you "stand up out of the chair" at the intro and go to the terminal, then it will show a (non-standard) onscreen keyboard to use, but a USB keyboard will work aqlso

Comment: oh yes, some games provide limited support. My answer was directed to people who aren't yet used to the controllers and are thinking maybe a good old fashioned keyboard and mouse would work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the PS3 supports pretty much any standard USB keyboard or mouse.

Answer (score 0):

A little tutorial on the functions I've found with a keyboard in the browser:

Swap windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

Previous/Next pages: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

Menu: <kbd>F1</kbd>

Bookmarks: <kbd>F3</kbd>

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to use a keyboard in a flash game. Still looking though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a keyboard and mouse that is wireless but has a usb you can plug the usb in and play if the keyboard and mouse are switched on. I have had very recent experience with it.