# Are there any alternative controllers for BlackOps on PS3

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops, controllers

I have been continually frustrated by the way controls work on the standard PS3 controller. There is aim assist, but in general the controller "makes you miss". The L3/R3 sticks are woefully inadequate as you basically over compensate whilst lining up your target. I have tried to fool around with the sensitivity settings but to no avail.

I have found playing COD on the PC a much better experience as you can aim much more accurately with a mouse and keyboard.

Is there an equivalent for playing COD on the PS3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aim assist is available only in the campaign not in the multiplayer. The way it works is that it helps you 'snap' to the target nearest to the reticle while aiming down the sights. So maybe that snapping action is throwing you off. You can disable it and try.

It takes time to transition from PC to controller and while keyboard and mouse maybe more accurate, you will get used to the controller soon enough.

Now to answer the other part of your question, there are some non-standard controllers (read cheats) that provide extra functionality like this [one](http://www.evilcontrollers.com/products/modded-controllers/evil-specials/ps3-rapid-fire.html). But you can't use a [keyboard and mouse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/can-we-use-keyboard-mouse-on-ps3) to play regularly.

Comment: I know what you're saying about aim assist in the campaign. But you do get "stickiness" in multi-player if the target is right in your cross hairs.. Not really aim assist. But given how much I suck at COD4 I need all the help I can get, so I refer to it as aim-assist, although it's not. I do however like the rapid fire controller.. very handy if you have a G11 rifle in COD4.

Comment: it is possible that your connection is laggy ( like mine ) and the game corrects for the position of other players. Do you notice this behavior when the enemy is very close to you? Cause if you do, then it is quite possibly the lag thing. If you want a modded controller, there are quite a few options other than just rapid fire, but mind you there are all cheats :)

Comment: Lag is usually the most common reason for those "why did I miss" moments. The rest is getting practice with the PS3 controller.

Comment: There is definitely lag issues. I notice that when I'm blasting away, and then just drop dead. The replay from my opponent POV shows that I never fired a shot. Have checked my broadband and it's all fine. I acknowledge that there will be some lag, but it's always me that gets shot. It's enough to drive me back to playing WoW :(

Comment: you should find out about your NAT type and try to put your ps3 in dmz

Answer (score 1):

This one might look a little crazy but the Avenger controller for Xbox was just released and there is also one coming for PS3 sometime soon according to their website.

http://www.avengercontroller.com/ps3.php

Comment: Controllers now get "rigging" ? ... Yep.. it looks overly serious. I'm sure there are 14 yr olds salivating over that controler..LOL.